# Font in gedit changes when I input the first letter in a line

Tags: linux-mint, fonts, gedit

I think this is a rather strange problem. I am using gedit, and my current font in the settings is the default (Monospace 10). But some lines in my text file has a clearly different font:

[image: different font]

Still stranger, when I type a letter in that line, the font magically reverts to Monospace:

[image: revert to monospace]

My linux distro is Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca. My locale is `zh_CN`. I wonder what caused that problem, and how I can fix it.